# LINQ set limit within the result

Tags: c#, linq, limit

I have a list of integers :

```
 List<int> a = new List<int>();
            a.Add(1001);
            a.Add(1001);
            a.Add(1001);
            a.Add(1001);
            a.Add(2003);
            a.Add(2003);
            a.Add(2003);
```

I need to do a LINQ "Where" on this list and only return (or limit) 2 of each type of integers.
So the result should be :

```
1001
1001
2003
2003
```

Note : Response time is a major factor in returning the results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Group items by their value, and then select first two items from each group:

```
var result = a.GroupBy(i => i).SelectMany(g => g.Take(2));
```

Or query syntax (less beautiful in this case):

```
var result = from i in a
             group i by i into g
             from i in g.Take(2)
             select i;
```

---

Thus grouping will group all items, and only then results will be returned, you can write custom extension method, which will not hold all groups of items (less memory will be used) and return items in streaming way as they come from source sequence:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> LimitElementOccurences<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, int n)
{
    return source.GoodMethodName(n, t => t);
}

public static IEnumerable<T> LimitElementOccurences<T, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, int n, Func<T, TKey> keySelector)
{
    var stats = new Dictionary<TKey, int>();

    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        var key = keySelector(item);
        int returnedItemsCount;
        if (!stats.TryGetValue(key, out returnedItemsCount))
        {
            yield return item;
            stats.Add(key, 1);
            continue;
        }

        if (returnedItemsCount >= n)
            continue;

        yield return item;
        stats[key] = returnedItemsCount + 1;
    }
}
```

Usage is (sorry, can't imagine good method name)

```
var result = a.LimitElementOccurences(2);
```

Comment: May i suggest a.LimitElementOccurences() as something slightly better as a name?

Comment: Great extension! I will have to try this (performance wise) and only then I will be able to mark this an answered !

Comment: How would you modify this extension if I had a Class instead of integer to look into lets says List<SomeClass> and the property to look into would be the integer ID ?

Comment: @MurtazaMandvi you don't need to modify it: `list.LimitElementOccurences(2, sc => sc.ID)`